# Making transparent pixels black

Tags: python, opencv

I generated an image with an alpha channel, in python-opencv, the image contains specific masked areas, and the other unmasked area is transparent, and I want to get rid of the transparent pixels and have black pixels instead.

Code for the masking:

```
mask1 = np.ones_like(img)
mask1 = cv2.circle(mask1, center_coordinates, (int(r) - 50), (255,255,255), -1)
mask2 = np.ones_like(img)
mask2 = cv2.circle(mask2, center_coordinates, (int(r) + 50), (255,255,255), -1)

# subtract masks and make into single channel
mask = cv2.subtract(mask2, mask1)

result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask[:,:,0]
```

Comment: Remove the alpha channel and use it as a mask to make the image black where the mask is black. `image[mask==0] = (0,0,0)`

Comment: I tried this, and I just got a whole black image and not a masked image.

Comment: Show your mask and your image without the alpha channel.

Comment: Use image from your original img without the alpha channel. Don't apply the mask to the image with the alpha channel.